# Hide empty SubReport space in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

How can I suppress empty space of subreport in SSRS. I am passing Main tablix data to subreport as a parameter.

**Current Result:**

[image]

**Expected Result:** *So it there is empty subreport, then it should not show and the subreport 3 should merge with subreport 1 border.*

[image]

Comment: Did you put any expression on the visibility property of subreport?

Comment: yes I have put. but not working for me!

Comment: You can use an alternative solution: setting a minimum height for your subreport which can automatically grows if necessary.

Comment: You can try to set NoRowsMessage to empty string, although I'm not sure if this will help. NoRowsMessage should output in textbox instead of empty  subreport and I hope it can shrink to zero height if there is empty text.

Comment: @tezzo - but then also it'll show blank space as per it's width. I have already tried that, but I want to merge subreport 3 with subreport 1 as I have shown in expected result

Answer (score 1):

You can try inserting another tablix (with 3 **header rows** for 3 subreports) inside the main tablix detail row.
Then, set the visibility property of inner tablix rows with your conditions.

[image]